# How to send a query set throw the super method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I try to send the log attribute to the super get function and list all the logs although I want the filter that works on `BasicQUserSerializer`.

This is my viewsets:

```
class CustomerLogView(generics.ListAPIView):
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
queryset = QUser.objects.all()
serializer_class = BasicQUserSerializer
filter_backends = [OrderingFilter]
pagination_class = AdvancedPagination

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    account = get_object_or_404(Account, pk=kwargs['pk'])
    log =CustomerLogSerializer(LogEntry.objects.filter(account=account), many=True).data
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs,)
```

Serializer:

```
class CustomerLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
actor = BasicQUserSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = LogEntry
    fields = ('id', 'actor', 'account', 'changes', 'remote_addr', 'additional_data','timestamp')
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to do with that log variable?

Comment: i want to send it as a parameter to the super get method to list the logs, currently im listing the BasicQUserSerializer but i want to list the logs instead

Comment: But "send it as a parameter to the super get method" is the bit I don't understand. What are you expecting that method to do with it? And if you want to list logs, why have you set the serializer class to BasicQUserSerializer in the first place rather than CustomerLogSerializer?

Comment: the BasicQUserSerializer is inside the CustomerLogSerializer i want to order based on the user but i want to list the logs thats why im using the serializer class to BasicQUserSerializer

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't do that the way you have mentioned in the question. If you want to see all the logs, why not add a [**`SerializerMethodField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for that?

```
class CustomerLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    actor = BasicQUserSerializer()
    logs = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = LogEntry
        fields = ('id', 'actor', 'account', 'changes', 'remote_addr', 'additional_data','timestamp')

    def get_logs(self, obj):
       return CustomerLogSerializer(LogEntry.objects.filter(account=obj.account), many=True).data
```